# Powershell get list of containers to a variable

Tags: powershell

```
docker build -f dockerfile . --tag mockapi/mock --build-arg now=$(Get-Date -format yyyy.MM.dd.HH:mm)
docker run -d --env-file ./.env -p 44370:8443 mockapi/mock 
docker ps -q  --filter ancestor=mockapi/mock:latest 
$keyRead = read-host "Press Y then ENTER to unload the container ..."
if ( $keyRead -eq "Y" )
{
    ##docker stop <Container_ID>
    ##docker rm <Container_ID>
    Write-Output "Removed container"
    $keyRead = read-host "Press Y then ENTER to unload the image ..."
    if ( $keyRead -eq "Y" )
    {
        docker rmi mockapi/mock:latest
        Write-Output "Removed image"
    }
}
```

On line number 3 I want to get that output (a container id) to a variable.  So I can stop that container and then remove the container.

Comment: `$myVariable = docker ...`